# Using two theano functions together

Tags: python, theano

If I had something like:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function


a = T.dscalar('a')
b = T.dscalar('b')

first_func = a * b
second_func = a - b

first = function([a, b], first_func)
second = function([a, b], second_func)
```

and I wanted to create a third function that was `first_func(1,2) + second_func(3,4)`, is there a way to do this and create a function that is passed these two smaller functions as input?

I want to do something like:

```
third_func = first(a, b) + second(a,b)
third = function([a, b], third_func)
```

but this does not work.  What is the correct way to break my functions into smaller functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way to decompose function is in-terms of tensor variables, rather than function calls. This should work:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

a = T.dscalar('a')
b = T.dscalar('b')

first_func = a * b
second_func = a - b

first = function([a, b], first_func)
second = function([a, b], second_func)

third_func = first_func + second_func
third = function([a, b], third_func)
```

`third_func = first(a, b) + second(a,b)` does not work because function call need real values whereas `a` and `b` are tensor/symbolic variables. Basically one should define mathematical operations with tensors and then use function to evaluate values of these tensors.